# clickonce downloading binaries frm HTTPS site with Domain name mismatch certificate fails

Tags: clickonce

My application downloads the exe's and dll's from a HTTPS website with a certificate whose Subject name/Subject Alt Name does not match the user typed in URL address host. ClickOnce rejects the certificate and aborts the download. Is there a way to instruct ClickOnce to pop-up the certificate information to the user as the Browser does. So that the user can decide about the certificate and allow or deny the download.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's not a good fix for this.  One workaround is to add an entry in your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) that matches your certificate.  That way you can go to the url in your certificate and should avoid the cert warning.

While this works, you probably don't want hundreds of users editing their hosts file.  If you find another solution, please follow-up.

Comment: I had attempted this and it works, but as you mentioned this is not a highly desirable solution